# Spectral norm of projected matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonality, matrix-analysis

Let $M_{n,m}$ be the set of real matrices of $n\times m$, and let $T:M_{n,m}\to M_{n,m}$ be a orthogonal projection operator, i.e., $T$ is such that for any $A,B\in M_{n,m}$
$$T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B),$$ 
$$T(T(A))=T(A),$$
$$\langle T(A),B\rangle = \langle A,T(B)\rangle.$$
where $\langle A,B\rangle=tr(A^{\top}B)$. For $A\in M_{n,m}$ let $\|A\|$ be its spectral norm and $\|A\|_F$ its Frobenius norm. **I want to prove that**
$$
\|T(A)\|\leq \|A\|.
$$
I've been able to prove that $\|T(A)\|_F\leq \|A\|_F$ which is immediate since $\langle T(A),(I-T)(A)\rangle=0$ which implies that $\|A\|_F=\|T(A)+(I-T)(A)\|_F=\|T(A)\|_F+\|(I-T)(A)\|_F$.

For the spectral norm maybe I can use that $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$ but I can't prove that $x^{\top}T(A)^{\top}(I-T)(A)x=0$.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**: If it helps, the form of $T$ is $T(A)=A-P_1AP_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are some $n\times n$ and $m\times m$ projection matrices.

This question is motivated by the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.6256.pdf, proof of Theorem 1, page 9, inequality after equation (2.15).

Comment: Why is it that you are trying to prove the statement rather than verify it? Is there a reason that you suspect that it is true?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Because it is a very specific part of the proof of a theorem in a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.6256.pdf). I do not show all the context because it is very involved. I'll edit to give a more specific form of $T$.

Comment: Could you also state where in the paper the proof in question can be found?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Of course! You can see it in the edition I made.

Comment: You state "Define the orthogonal projector operator $T$ ..." There can be (and usually are) more than one $T$ that satisfies those equations (for example the identity matrix satisfies those equations). Could be you be more specific, please?

Comment: @PedroJuanSoto I just did in the last edit. You have a point, but I think I'm suggesting that I'm not considering a particular operator, but all orthogonal projection operators. Sorry If It wasn't clear. Anyway, I just described $T$ explicitly...

Comment: As seems to be the case in the context of the paper, I think we should assume that $\operatorname{rank}(P_1) = \operatorname{rank}(P_2) = r$. Note that up to an orthogonal change of basis, your operator can be written in the form
$$
T \pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21} & A_{22}} = \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\A_{21} & 0}, 
$$
where $A_{11}$ is the upper-left $r \times r$ submatrix of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the observation. Can you give some explanation on why $T(A)$ has that form? It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. E.g. suppose that $n=m=2$ and $T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the linear span of $B=\operatorname{diag}(6,3)$. Let $A=5I$. Then $T(A)=B$ because $\langle A-B,B\rangle=\langle \operatorname{diag}(-1,2),\operatorname{diag}(6,3)\rangle=0$. However, $\|T(A)\|_2=\|B\|_2=6>5=\|A\|_2$.

Another counterexample: let
\begin{aligned}
&T(X)=X-\pmatrix{1\\ &0}X\pmatrix{1\\ &0},\\
&A=\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 1&1},\ B=T(A)=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1},
\end{aligned}
then $\|T(A)\|_2=\|B\|_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx1.618>1.414\approx\sqrt{2}=\|A\|_2$.

---

**Remark.** The inequality that motivated the OP's question, namely,
$$
\|T(A)\|_F\le\sqrt{\operatorname{rank}(T(A))}\,\|A\|_2
$$
where $T(A)=A-P_1AP_2$ for some two orthogonal projectors $P_1$ and $P_2$, is correct. Without loss of generality, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W}
\ \text{ and }\ T(A)=\pmatrix{0&Y\\ Z&W}.
$$
Let $Y=U_y(S_y\oplus0)V_y^T$ and $Z=U_z(S_z\oplus0)V_z^T$ be two singular value decompositions, where $S_y$ and $S_z$ are two positive diagonal matrices. Define on $M_{n,m}$ a linear map
$$
F:B\mapsto\pmatrix{U_y\\ &U_z}^TB\pmatrix{V_z\\ &V_y}.
$$
Then we may write
$$
F(A)=
\left(\begin{array}{c&c|c&c}\ast&\ast&S_y&0\\ \ast&\ast&0&0\\ \hline S_z&0&E&F\\ 0&0&G&H\end{array}\right)
\ \text{ and }\ F(T(A))=
\left(\begin{array}{c&c|c&c}0&0&S_y&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ \hline S_z&0&E&F\\ 0&0&G&H\end{array}\right).
$$
Let
$$
M_1=\pmatrix{S_y\\ 0\\ 0\\ G}\ \text{ and }\ M_2=\pmatrix{S_z&0&E&F}.
$$
Since $M_1,M_2$ and $H$ are submatrices of $F(A)$, their spectral norms are bounded above by $\|F(A)\|_2$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
\|T(A)\|_F^2
&=\|F(T(A))\|_F^2\\
&=\|M_1\|_F^2+\|M_2\|_F^2+\|H\|_F^2\\
&\le\operatorname{rank}(M_1)\|M_1\|_2^2+\operatorname{rank}(M_2)\|M_2\|_2^2+\operatorname{rank}(H)\|H\|_2^2\\
&\le\left(\operatorname{rank}(M_1)+\operatorname{rank}(M_2)+\operatorname{rank}(H)\right)\|F(A)\|_2^2\\
&=\operatorname{rank}(F(T(A)))\|F(A)\|_2^2\\
&=\operatorname{rank}(T(A))\|A\|_2^2.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Nice counterexample. Do you think that the result is true for the specific choice of $T(A)=A-P_1AP_2$ that I present at the end of the question?

Comment: Thanks! So I guess that this affirmation in the paper is wrong...

Comment: Yes, but a previous step to obtain that inequality is $$\|P_A(M)\|_F\leq \sqrt{rank(P_A(M))}\|P_A(M)\|_{\infty}.$$ So I was thinking that they implicitly say that $\|P_A(M)\|_{\infty}\leq \|M\|_{\infty}$ (which is what I asked.) If it is not true, Then why does the inequality of the paper holds?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with that. That's why I asked this question: If the sufficient condition does not hold, I have strong beliefs that the inequality is not true since a more involved argument will be placed on the paper. Of course, I'm not certain. Do you think that there is a way to prove the main inequality?

Comment: @RLC I think it's true. Please see my new edit.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be clear to me. I just have one question about the procedure: why without loss of generality we can assume that form for $T$?

Comment: @RLC Just change the bases. $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal projectors. Therefore for each $i$ we have $P_i=Q_i(I_{r_i}\oplus 0)Q_i^T$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q_i$, with $r_i$ being the rank of $P_i$. Hence $$Q_1^TT(A)Q_2=Q_1^TAQ_2-(I_{r_1}\oplus0)Q_1^TAQ_2(I_{r_2}\oplus0).$$

Answer (score 0):

> As the other poster has shown, this is not true in general **but it is
>   true in the special case where $T$ takes the form $T: A \mapsto PA $**;
>   *i.e.* $T$ is left multiplication by some matrix $n \times n $ matrix $P$. As
>   you have pointed out there are more general tensors that satisfy the
>   definition, but it is true in this special case.

The spectral norm of $A$ for a real matrix is equal to 
\begin{equation}
|A| = \sup_{|x| = 1} \|Ax\| = \sup_{x \neq 0 } \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.
\end{equation}

Suppose for a contradiction that 
\begin{equation}
|TA|   > |A|
\end{equation}
then using the vector norm $\| \| $ there is some $v$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\|T(Av)\| =\|(TA)v\|   > \|Av\|
\end{equation}
and therefore setting $x=Av$
we have that 
\begin{equation}
 \|Tx\|^{2}=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle =\langle Tx,x\rangle \leq \|Tx\|\cdot \|x\|
\end{equation}
and therefore we have that 
\begin{equation}
 \|Tx\| \leq  \|x\|
\end{equation}
and that 
\begin{equation}
 \|Tx\| >  \|x\|
\end{equation}
which is a contradiction. **QED**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Unfortunately, it seems to have a mistake: $T(x)$ is not well defined. That's why I said that $T:M_{n,m}\to M_{n,m}$. Look at the particular choice $T(A) = A-P_1AP_2$ (it's easy to see that this is a orthogonal projector). You can see from this that $T(A)v\neq T(Av)$ in general. Tell me if I misunderstood something of your proof.

Comment: I have modified my post. Thanks for pointing that out!